# change font by javascript without value parameter but with text

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating dynamic drop down and i want to get name of option.Since there is no value we cannot use

```
document.querySelector('#hello').style.color=this.value;
```

so--

```
<select id="hello">
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
</select>

<h1>HELLO</h1>


document.querySelector('#hello').onChange=function(){
               document.querySelector('h1').style.fontSize="120px";
               document.querySelector('h1').style.color=red;
               document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML='1222';

           };
```

what i want is to change h1 color , size and innerHTML when option a to b is changed.

how to change HELLO h1 tag with text b/w option 
**HELLO to a**
*HELLO to b*
respectively

Comment: Use google. Useful links:
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: Is the h1 supposed to change differently based on if the user selects a or b? Or is is it just supposed to fire on any change?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, make below changes

1.Change **onChange** to **onchange**(lowercase)
Please refer onchange event details from this link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange

2. provide color value in quotes i.e document.querySelector('h1').style.color='red'

codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/PdGVrO?editors=1010

```js
document.querySelector('#hello').onchange=function(){
               document.querySelector('h1').style.fontSize="120px";
               document.querySelector('h1').style.color='red';
               document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML='1222';

           };
```

```html
<select id="hello">
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
</select>

<h1>HELLO</h1>
```